# Call request.session var inside jquery

Tags: jquery, django, request, session-variables

Got this session variable in a html template :

```
request.session["rer_value"]
```

And i need to call it inside a jquery code that is located in another html template to make some calculations:

```
vrer= request.session["rer_value"];

    $('table').on('change', '.usd_value', function() {
      pesos_value = $(this).closest('tr').find('.pesos_value');
      percent = $(this).closest('tr').find('.percent');

      //$(pesos_value).val($(this).val() * vrer);

    });
```

But itś not working....any idea ?, thanks for your help !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That isn't going to work, is it, because `request.session` is an object on the server, not in the client-side Javascript.

If you want to make that value available for jQuery to use, you will need to pass it explicitly into the template from the view.

in your view:

```
return render(request, 'mytemplate.html', {'vrer':  request.session["rer_value"], ...})
```

in your template:

```
var vrer = "{{ vrer }}"
```